# Flutter: BloC inject mocks in app testing

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, flutter-test, flutter-bloc

I'm trying to create a flutter app using flutter_bloc, firebase auth and firestore.

I following [flutter_firebase_login example](https://github.com/felangel/bloc/tree/master/examples/flutter_firebase_login) which is truly amazing for all the testing coverage.

I would like to go one step further. Once the use is authenticated, I want to load the user profile from firestore, then actually display the app. (In practice, once the profile is loaded, I will have to do new firestore lookups that will depend on the profile info).

So I kind of have a chain of events:
Authenticate -> Load profile for user "uid" -> Load data depending on profile.

I'm wondering what is the good way to do that which still allows me to test my full app using mocks only.

[The example](https://github.com/felangel/bloc/blob/master/examples/flutter_firebase_login/lib/app.dart) injects the authenticationRepository into the App class then we can inject it in the test. My problem now is that, once the user is logged in and we redirect to the HomePage widget, this widget will have to create a new provider. But if it does create a new one, then I can't inject it anymore.

What is the good practice there? Here are the few options I've been considering:

**Inject all the providers in the main()**

I guess this would be the simplest solution. Though since those providers are kind of chained, I would have to pass the context data to every call on the "sub" providers, the context from the previous one. For instance:

```
ProfileRepository {
  ... getProfile(uid);
}

DataRepository {
  ... getData(... profile)
}
```

**Dynamically build the providers**

Ideally, I would like to not need those extra params in my providers and instead build my providers with those context values. Example:

```
ProfileRepository {
  ProfileRepository(uid)...
  ... getProfile();
}

DataRepository {
  DataRepository(profile)...
  ... getData()
}
```

So each time the uid changes, we would create a new provider for the profile and for each profile change we would create a new data provider.

This will simplify the calls in my app to not have to load the profile to get the data. The sub widgets just need to get the current provider and call the functions without the depending contexts.

Though just calling the constructor from my widgets would create problems for the tests DI which means I would have to create provider factories that I could then inject. And from the tests I would pass mock factories and in my main(), the prod factories.

**Adding a state to my providers**

I would inject all my factories in the main but instead of constructing them using the uid or the profile. Pseudo code:

```
ProfileRepository {
  setUid(uid)...
  ... getProfile();
}

DataRepository {
  setProfile(profile)...
  ... getData(... otherParams)
}
```

Each time the user changes or the profile changes, I just call the setters. That way I don't need to pass provider factories from the main.

**Note**

I considered to wrap the AuthenticationRepository into a UserProfileRepository which would remove one step here but for the data, this would not work.

I'm not sure what is the good practice here and would love to get feedback.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The main idea of unit testing is that you'd mock (and make predictable) all the values that are external to the class (called software under test) that you're writing the unit test for. Whatever method that allows you to achieve that is good. Whichever of those methods that give you the best results with the least amount of work is the best. Constructor injection is the simplest and probably the most popular type of dependency injection. This is roughly equivalent to the second code snippet you posted.

Comment: I agree with that comment, here I'm trying to get an experienced insight of the good practice here so I don't have to try one solution that I will have to rewrite yet another time in a couple weeks.